# Как корректно добавить ссылку?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

Новичок в thymeleaf. Через контроллер передается список объектов Person и в html отображаются в виде нумерованного списка person.firstName, person.lastName и person.patronymic. Хочу каждую строку нумерованного списка сделать в виде ссылке, при переходе по которой будут редактироваться данные выбранного объекта Person. Написал такой код - данные выводятся корректно, но они не в виде ссылки:

```
<div >
    <ol>
       <li th:each="person : ${persons}" th:text="${person.getLastName()} + ' ' + ${person.getFirstName()} + ' ' + ${person.getPatronymic()}">
           <a th:href="/person/${person.id}">Редактировать</a>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a th:href="@{/person/${person.id}}">Редактировать</a>
```

или

```
<a th:href="@{'/person/' + ${person.id}}">Редактировать</a>
```